# How return value after create data firestore

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm trying to create data using firestore like below this

```
createData({state}) {
        return db.collection('items').add({
            title: state.title,
            ingredients: state.ingredients,
            createdAt: new Date()
        })
            .then( ref => {
                console.log(ref.id)
            });
    }
```

How to return the value of items that were just created?
result **ref.id** just for id document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use **onSnapshot** method to resolve my question.

```
                ref.onSnapshot(doc => {
                    console.log(doc.data())
                });
```

Comment: This is a good example. Answering our post whenever we solve our problem in order to share information on how to tackle the problem so, anybody sees this post can save their time.